# Converting .txt file to list AND be able to index and print list line by line

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to be able to read the file line by line and then when prompted (say user inputs 'background'), it returns lines 0:24 because those are the lines in the .txt that relate to his/her background.

```
def anaximander_background():
    f = open('Anaximander.txt', 'r')
    fList = []
    fList = f.readlines()
    fList = [item.strip('\n') for item in fList]
    print(fList[:20])
```

This code prints me the list like:

```
['ANAXIMANDER', '', 'Anaximander was born in Miletus in 611 or 610 BCE.', ...]
```

I've tried a lot of different ways (for, if, and while loops) and tried the csv import.

The closest I've gotten was being able to have a print out akin to:

```
[ANAXIMANDER]
[]
[info]
```

and so on, depending on how many objects I retrieve from `fList`.

I really want it to print like the example I just showed but without the list brackets ([ ]).

Definitely can clarify if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either loop over the list, or use `str.join()`:

```
for line in fList[:20]:
    print(line)
```

or

```
print('\n'.join(fList[:20])
```

The first print each element contained in the `fList` slice separately, the second joins the lines into a new string with `\n` newline characters between them before printing.

Comment: Yes excellent!!  Thank you so much!  I knew it was something relatively simple but I get mentally blocked easily whenever I hit a wall.

Answer (score 1):

To print the first 20 lines from a file:

```
import sys
from itertools import islice

with open('Anaximander.txt') as file:
    sys.stdout.writelines(islice(file, 20))
```